# Libgdx - Mtx textures are not shown on the screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I tried to recreate the menu from the [mtx flame words example](http://moribitotechx.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/61-tutorial-libgdx-mtx-21-flame-words.html.com),but nothing from the menu shows up on the screen.There is no problem with the assets because i'm able to use them with spritebatch.It's almost 1:1 with the example and i couldn't figure out where is the problem.

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends AbstractScreen implements IScreen{

private MainMenuScreenButtons mainMenuScreenButtons;
public MainMenuScreen(AbstractGame game, String screenName) {
    super(game, screenName);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setUpScreenElements();
    setUpMenu();
}

@Override
public void setUpScreenElements() {
    setOpenGLClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f);
    setBackgroundTexture(Assets.background);
}

@Override
public void setUpMenu() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mainMenuScreenButtons = new MainMenuScreenButtons(MainMenuScreen.this);

}

public MainMenuScreenButtons getMainMenuScreenButtons() {
    return mainMenuScreenButtons;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.render(delta);
}
}
```

MainMenuScreenButtons

```
public class MainMenuScreenButtons {
private MainMenuScreen mainMenuScreen;

private Table tableMain;
private Table tableButtons;

private ButtonLight btnPlay;

public MainMenuScreenButtons(MainMenuScreen mainMenuScreen) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mainMenuScreen = mainMenuScreen;
    setUp();
}

public void setUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tableMain = new Table();
    tableMain.setFillParent(true);
    tableButtons = new Table();


            btnPlay = new ButtonLight(310,130,Assets.buttons,true);

            UtilsOrigin.setActorOrigin(btnPlay, Origin.CENTER);

            tableButtons.add(btnPlay).row();
            tableButtons.center();
            tableMain.add(tableButtons).center();
            mainMenuScreen.getStage().addActor(tableMain);
}

}
```

Comment: What is your specific question?  Do you see any error messages when you run the code?

Comment: No errors , just nothing shows on the screen except the background from setBackgroundTexture(Assets.background);

Answer (score 1):

try to use gdx texture packer https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/
then change the extension to text and delete the first empty and clean your projects.

Comment: Tried it , still not working , only the background from setBackgroundTexture(Assets.background); is showing